# Laravel's chunkById ambiguous column

Tags: php, laravel, chunks

When i use chunkById on a Query Builder with joins, i get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42702]: Ambiguous column: 7 ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous

```php
$query = \DB::table('table1')
            ->select([
                'table1.id'
            ])
            ->join('table2', 'table2.table1_id', '=', 'table1.id')
            ->orderBy('table1.id', 'DESC');

$query->chunkById(1000, function ($items) {
   //do something
});
```

It works for the first chunk then it throws the error. Is there any way to specify the table of the id that laravel uses to keep track of the chunks?

- Laravel Version: 5.7.28
- PHP Version: 7.3.1
- Database Driver & Version: postgres 10

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need two more parameters:

```
$query->chunkById(1000, function ($items) {
   //do something
}, 'table1.id', 'id');
```

Read the API doc of Laravel to more details about the third and forth columns: [Laravel API doc](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_chunkById)

Comment: Broken link. Found some form of older documentation [here](https://docs1.w3cub.com/laravel~5.2/api/5.2/illuminate/database/eloquent/builder/#method_chunkById)

Comment: Previous link is also broken, try this: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.html#method_chunkById